# Split lines by delimiter to parse a text file

Tags: c++, csv

I'm writing a program that takes a txt file like this:

foo.txt:

```
Aaaa/NGACG/NGAA//
Aaab/AGGGC//
Aaac/CTN/AGGC/NNA//
```

And in each line it stores the ID (Aaa..) into a vector (once for each value), and the values separated by / into strings.

So the first line would be:

```
    foo.push_back("Aaaa");
    string bar = NGACG;
    foo.push_back("Aaaa");
    string bar2 = NGAA;
```

The pseudocode is something like this:

```
while (not end of file)
{
    while (not end of line)
    {
        while (next char isn't /)
        {
            temporary string x += char
        }
        foo.push_back(string)       //ID

        while (next char isn't /)
        {
            string bar += char      //value
        }
    }
}
```

My pseudocode is obviously flawed, but that's the general idea of what I want to do. I've looked up guides on how to parse, but nothing really works for my purposes. How can I do this without being completely inefficient? I can't think of how to write this without using an arbitrary number of while loops

Comment: Have you thought of using something like [boost::split](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp430824992)?

Comment: Or just scanf, which accepts some rudimentary pattern as conversions; in a loop, read anything that's not a slash, then read away the slash. Something like this (but with EOF checks): `if( scanf("%[^/]", buf) == 1 ) { strcpy(val, buf); } getchar(); // "/" }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it *the good old C way* with `fgets` and `strtok`:

```
char line[SIZE];   // make sure SIZE is greater than your longest input line ...
char *ix;
while(fgets(line), SIZE, fdin) {
    line[strcspn("\n")] = '\0'; // remove EOL
    ix = strtok(line, "/");
    foo.push_back(string(ix));
    string bar = string(strtok(NULL, "/"));
    string bar2 = string(strtok(NULL, "/"));
    ...
}
```

Or you can use a `stringstream` and `std::getline` with the delimiter parameter:

```
string line;
while(getline(fdin, line)) {
    string temp, bar, bar2;
    istringstream is(line);
    getline(is, temp, '/');
    foo.push_back(temp);
    getline(is, bar);
    getline(is, bar2);
    ...
}
```

Of course, you should add tests for error conditions...

Answer (score 0):

You can read the lines (or the whole file) into simple char arrays and use the lines you have read directly: simply replace `/` with `'\0'` and point char pointers to the next char into the very lines, without copying anything. The null bytes terminate the "values" between the slashes in the original data and are C strings of their own for all intents and purposes.